# how to add event for drop-down component to change subdomain by selected item

Tags: ember.js, express, ember-data, subdomain, ember-cli

i use pod structure with ember cli. i have a 'drop-down' component.

**in my drop-down.js component:**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
  var component = Ember.Component.extend({
  tagName: '', //remove extra div wrapper.
  valueKey: 'id',
  textKey: 'text',
  options: [],
  value: null,
  defaultText: 'select...',
  selected: function () {
    var valueKey = this.get('valueKey');
    var textKey = this.get('textKey');
    var defaultText = this.get('defaultText');
    var fallbackOption = {};
    fallbackOption[valueKey] = 0;
    fallbackOption[textKey] = defaultText;

    if (Ember.isEmpty(this.get('value'))) {
      return fallbackOption;
    }

    var selected = this.get('options').findProperty(valueKey,this.get('value'));

    return selected ? selected : fallbackOption;
  }.property('options', 'value'),
  actions: {
    select(option) {
      var valueKey = this.get('valueKey');
      this.set('value', option[valueKey]);
    }
  }
});

export default component;
```

i have used this component in index to load countries.

**in template.hbs for index :**

```
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6 input-padding">
   {{drop-down options=model.countries
     value=country
     valueKey=valueKey
     textKey=textKey
     defaultText=defaultText}}
 </div>
```

i want to add change event to countries dropdown, that it must change subdomain by country. for example, when i select Iran, its event causes my subdomain changes to 'Iran.site.com.
how can i add this event? and where should i add it ?thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an action to your component and when you select an option, you can send it up using the `sendAction` method.

Your component will look like the below code. In that I have added an extra property `action="countrySelected"` where countrySelected is an action defined in either your controller or route.

```
{{drop-down options=model.countries
  value=country
  valueKey=valueKey
  textKey=textKey
  defaultText=defaultText
  action="countrySelected"
}}
```

Now you need to modify the `select` action in your component code like

```
select(option) {
  var valueKey = this.get('valueKey');
  this.set('value', option[valueKey]);
  this.sendAction('action', valueKey , option[valueKey]);
}
```

Here the last line is the relevant line. You are now calling the `countrySelected` action which can be defined either in the page's controller or route.

Comment: Thanks @blessenm , would you please help me about subdomains ?i want to change url 'www.website.com' to 'iran.website.com',when i select 'iran' from my dropdown. how can i do that?

Comment: AFAIK, Changing a subdomain is like going to a new site. You can use window.location = 'iran.website.com'